# iCloud Backup not completing

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, ios-appstore

I have an iPhone 5 on iOS 8.4.1. I recently jailbroke it and then restored it back using iTunes. Since then, iCloud Backup is not completing even after me doing it manually over and over again.

Also, AppStore is too slow, the app download or update doesn't even start. Upon waiting for few hours, it completes about 5%

What could this be?

Answer (score 1):

I updated to iOS 9 last night and iCloud Backup works fine now

and for the AppStore issue, I disabled the Two-Step Verification while still on iOS 8.4.1 and it worked